# http to https multisite 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a multisite (wordpress) consisting of 21 sites. Some are sub domains and some are URLs.

I'm now going to move the entire multisite from http to https.

What do I add to the .htaccess file?

http:// www. example .com

http:// www. example .nl

http:// www. example .de

http:// no. example .com

http:// fi. example .com

To make it even more difficult I need to move and redirect the http:// www. example .nl domain to a directory on the primary domain like https:// www. example .com/nl/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try following rules

```html
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/nl/$1 [R,L]
```

```html
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```